# What is the ten minutes?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

In the first episode of Battlestar Galactica, 33, what is the ten minutes that Colonel Tigh and Commander Adama are rotating? Originally I thought it was ten minutes speaking to the President but have realized that ten minutes sleep might be more appropriate.

Comment: It appears to be ten minutes downtime. Not necessarily sleep, but just time away from the bridge.

Comment: It's not explained further but sleep (or at least rest) would seem to be the most reasonable explanation.

Comment: Enough time to use the restroom, splash cold water on your face, change your shirt, maybe just scream and break stuff - whatever you need to do to clear your head.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the show's [original script](http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/Battlestar_Galactica/Battlestar_Galactica_1x01_-_33.pdf), the implication seems to be that Tigh and Adama are taking it in turns to have ten minutes ***downtime*** away from the bridge, time enough to [SSS](http://readyayeready.com/jackspeak/termview.php?id=1801).

Note that Tigh has maneuvered the captain to his quarters in this earlier draft.

> [They’ve arrived **outside Adama’s quarters**. He glances at his watch.]
>
> **ADAMA:** *This my ten minutes or yours?*
>
> **TIGH:** *Yours, I took ten last time.*
>
> **ADAMA:** *See you two in Combat.*